# how to improve the processing time of my R code

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, for-loop, bioconductor

I need to make some manipulation to a dataset but my [r](/questions/tagged/r) script (shown below) is running really slow. The data set is a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) that has dimension: 58347 x 41350. I tried to first run the R script below on a much smaller dataset (58347 x 5) and it took me an hour to process it. I would imagine it's going to take much longer to process the actual dataset. **Do you guys know any way to make it run faster?**

Please see my codes below:

```
library("LoomExperiment")
dataset<-import("WongAdultRetina homo_sapiens 2019-11-08 16.13.loom")
m<-assay(dataset)
colsums<-colSums(m)
result<-data.frame()
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(m))){
    if(i%%500==0){
      print(paste("i =",i))
    }
    for(j in seq_len(ncol(m))){
      if(colsums[j]== 0){
        result[i,j]<- 0
      }
      else {
        result[i,j]<-(m[i,j]*2000)/colsums[j]
      }
    }
  }
save(result,file="resultlocal.rda")
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: For starters one of the loops/if-then-else statement can be replaced an `ifelse()` function. Without any sample data to test or explanation of the calculations, I will this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do in the code? That will make it easier to provide an alternate solution. Just a note -- using dplyr, purrr and/or data.table may be faster than using for loops for matrices.

Comment: there is a matrix of dimension 58347 x 41350. I am trying to process the number in each cell by first dividing it by its column sum (a very large number) then multiply it by 2000 so that the numbers are not infinitely close to 0. In short, I am trying to normalize the numbers in each cell so that they are comparable

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but I am still waiting for a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what to do without understanding exactly what you're trying to achieve here. But I'll try.

First, you can replace `data.frame` with `data.table`. From my experience they're much faster to work with.

Second, you can create `result` data.frame with a specified size. For example, it looks like it will always have a size of `nrow(m) by ncol(m)`. So, `result = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(m), ncol = ncol(m)))`. Of course you can always replace it with `data.table` too.
Specifying the size of `data.frame` will allocate enough memory to the object. This way, `R` won't have to grow (copy the contents of original frame into an object that is one unit bigger and then delete the original) the object to just add another element.